# Access Automator variables from AppleScript

Tags: variables, applescript, automator

When AppleScript is used in Automator, is it possible to import/get multiple variables that have already been defined in Automator, and then set multiple variables in AppleScript, rather than having to do this on the output after the AppleScript?  I want to use these variables later in the Automator.

Answer (score 0):

**Keep all of the variables in AppleScript?**

If I were you, I would consider having a single AppleScript and have it execute the various workflows that you might need.  What I'm suggesting may require that you breakup your existing workflow into multiple workflows so that they can all be controlled by the single AppleScript to execute them.

Let me know how it goes.  I'd be interested to see your solution or to give you more help.